# Efficient use of in

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a tuple containing a large number of tuples (1500 tuples to be exact), as follows:

```
l = ( ("i",), ("i", "am"), ("im",), ("im", "here"), ("go",) ...)
```

The items in `l`are unique.

I wish to find items in this list as follows:

```
if i in l:
  do_something_with(i)
```

How can I make this lookup efficient? Should I sort `l`? Would it be more efficient to search the list in this form:

```
l = ( "i", "i am", "im", "im here", "go" ...)
```

Comment: Not that it makes a difference, but `("im")` in the middle of your tuple is simply a string, it's not a `tuple`.

Comment: @mgilson Good catch, but it does make a difference if he actually has a tuple consisting of "im" when he does the membership test.

Comment: @phant0m -- Maybe I should have said that it doesn't really make a difference to how `in` (`__contains__`) behaves.  It could possibly have a significant effect on the program's output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lookups in lists and tuples are always inefficient; use a `set()` instead:

```
lookupl = set(l)
```

Testing for membership in a set is constant cost (O(1)), while list and tuple membership tests have linear cost (O(n)).

Comment: The items in l are unique, will the set make a difference in this case?

Comment: @Baz: yes, it's the lookup that is taking time, not wether or not they are unique.

Comment: OP is asking about `tuple`, not `list` (although that doesn't actually change any of the content).  Perhaps you should say `sequences` instead?

Comment: @mgilson: I made it `lists and tuples`.

Comment: Do you have an idea of roughly what the tipping point is where the saved lookup time offsets the extra time it takes to turn the `tuple` in to a `set`?

Comment: @sr2222: Don't do this just once. Save the set and re-use it for lookups, or there is no point in using a set (creating it takes O(n) time too). When testing repeatedly against a set beats testing against the list depends entirely on the size of the list and the number of tests you make.

Comment: Well yeah, of course.  But if you need your data ordered, and you also want to be able to membership test quickly, that leaves you keeping 2 versions of the data in memory, which starts to introduce its own problems, especially since this optimization is mainly for large datasets.

Comment: @sr2222: The alternative for ordered data is to use binary search, or to use a binary tree. The OP never said that their `l` sequence was ordered.